# Best place set global session variables?

Tags: laravel

I am writing my first app in Laravel and I want to set some global session variables when the user first accesses the app.

What is the best practice for this? Middleware?

Using Laravel 8

Comment: Perhaps you could provide further information such as what type of data and its purpose as that would be helpful.

Comment: I can, but not sure how to be more precise than saying that I am loading variable data (text, integers, etc) that are going to be used globally. For example, there is an account ID that is tied to each user that will need to be reference throughout. I want to load that data when the user accesses the app from any page. So, i want to check to see if that value is already stored and, if not, store it.

Comment: That example sounds like a [`relationship`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) between an `Account` and `User`. You can access model relationships on any page, no need to involve `sessions`. It's still a little vague unfortunately. If you can expand your example further (are the users registered, if you login with no account id what happens? etc.) we could help. Might also be worthwhile watching [Laravel from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch).

Comment: Good point.  Yes, user is authenticated via the Laravel authentication. I am current accessing user data in the manner you suggest. Sounds like that the best direction.